# Calculating correlation between embedding features

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, embeddings, features

I am looking for a technique to calculate correlation for embedding features (array of floats). I'm interested in the correlation between features (embedding-embedding) as well as between feature and prediction target (embedding-float). Ideally I'd like to get a single value representing the correlation.

I'm having trouble finding resources on the topic. Pearson does not apply to a vector case. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It is not quite clear why you are trying to do this. Do you have a mechanism to create embedding vectors, e.g. for each individual and you have two sub-populations, and you are trying to check correlations between their features? Or are you trying to compare two embedding vectors?

Comment: Explain why the Pearson correlation coefficient is not suitable for your task? Each coordinate of a vector embedding can be considered as a separate feature. On the basis of which you can build a correlation matrix.

Comment: @Cryo I have access to several different embedding vectors which represent different aspects of user behaviour. I'd like to be able to compare between embeddings for the purpose of feature selection and adding new features. E.g. correlation to drop highly correlated embeddings, understanding if a new embedding provides new signal.

Comment: @Gromov If possible I would like to get a single number that represents the correlation between the embeddings. That way I can compare how different embeddings correlate with the target variable, especially if two embeddings vectors have different sizes. As far as I know it's not meaningful to aggregate correlation values, so I couldn't just average the correlation matrix.

Alternately, if there are suggestions on how to interpret and compare correlation matrices that would be helpful too.

Comment: @DrewSerles, you could put all your individual embedding vectors into a matrix and then use [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). This will take care of linear correlations automatically. A good way to frame your problem is to suppose there is a 'true' vector of features, and then all your embedding vectors are linear transforms from that vector. Not sure it is a good idea to granulate your analysis to component level.